# python pandas pulling two values out of the same column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

What I have is a basic dataframe that I want to pull two values out of, based on index position. So for this:

| first_column | second_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |

I want to extract the values in row 1 and row 2 (1 2) out of first_column, then extract values in row 2 and row 3 (2 3) out of the first_column, so on and so forth until I've iterated over the entire column. I ran into an issue with the four loop and am stuck with getting the next index value.

I have code like below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'first_column':  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'second_column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row['first_column']) # value1
    print(index + 1, row['first_column'].values(index + 1)) # value2 <-- error in logic here
```

Ignoring the prints, which will eventually become variables that are returned, how can I improve this to return (1 2), (2 3), (3 4), (4 5), etc.?

Also, is this easier done with iteritems() method instead of iterrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve:

```py
(temp= df.assign(second_column = df.second_column.shift(-1))
         .dropna()
         .assign(second_column = lambda df: df.second_column.astype(int))
)

[*zip(temp.first_column.array, temp.second_column.array)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

A simpler solution from @HenryEcker:

```py
list(zip(df['first_column'], df['first_column'].iloc[1:]))
```

Comment: I think it's actually just the one column "out of the first_column, so on and so forth until I've iterated over the entire column". `list(zip(df['first_column'], df['first_column'].shift(-1).dropna().astype(int)))`

Comment: ahhh ... yes, the second column is a duplicate it seems

Comment: Sorry for the edit, but I realized it could be even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you Want to take these items in the same fashion you should consider using `iloc` instead of using `iterrow`.

```py
out = []
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    print(i, df.iloc[i]["first_column"])
    print(i+1, df.iloc[i+1]["first_column"])
    out.append((df.iloc[i]["first_column"],
                df.iloc[i+1]["first_column"]))
print(out)
```

```sh
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: That seems to return me 0 1 , 1 2 , 1 2, 2 3 ... which is close but has duplicates

Comment: I saved the results on a list called `out` I don't see duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but maybe you can try this :

```
for i, val in enumerate(df['first_column']):
    if val+1>5:
        break
    else:
        print(val,", ",val+1)
```

Comment: I think you're in the right direction, the only problem is that it returns a simple addition. If the first_column in the df was something like (1,6,4,3,7,9,4,10,25,...) then the logic kinda falls apart. For an array like the one I just mentioned, it should return 1 6, 6 4, 4 3, 3 7, 7 9, etc...